# Is it possible to allow users to do custom html/css as inputs buttons to alter text similar to common text editors (like word/excel) in a R Shiny app?

Tags: html, r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity

So I have a simple shiny app that takes text as an input and outputs it.

But my goal is to make it easier for my users to be able to customize the font and formatting of this text in an easy to use way.

Here is a screenshot of the app (below). I can enter HTML code to change the formatting but my users do not know HTML or CSS.

[image]

Is there an easy way for my users to be able to have a little UI with basic formatting that can be passed through the input? Kind of like this?

[image]

Here is my app code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    textAreaInput("text", label = HTML(paste0("Enter Text Here")), value = HTML(paste0("HTML ELEMENTS CAN BE USED"))),
  mainPanel(
    uiOutput("value"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$value <- reactive({
    shiny::HTML(paste0(input$text)) 
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You have a typo.  Replace `output$value <- reactive({...` with `output$value <- renderUI({...`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JavaScript library [SunEditor](https://github.com/JiHong88/SunEditor)

```r
library(shiny)

js <- '
$(document).ready(function(){
  const editor = SUNEDITOR.create(document.getElementById("editor"), {});
});
'

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$link(rel="stylesheet", href = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/suneditor@latest/dist/css/suneditor.min.css"),
    tags$script(src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/suneditor@latest/dist/suneditor.min.js"),
    tags$script(HTML(js))
  ),
  br(),
  tags$textarea(id = "editor", class = "sun-editor-editable", cols = 80)
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, what would you need on server side to pass the values over to something like `textOutput()`

Comment: @RL_Pug Not sure to understand. Why do you want to pass the values? And the formatting will be lost, if this is possible, I think.